# Password won't work right after installation

Tags: postgresql

I just installed postgresql 9.3 on my Windows machine.  During the installation, the installer asked for a password. I inputted a password and continued on my merry way.  The system never asked for a user to associate with this password.

I then typed psql at the command prompt so that I could begin playing around with a DB.  The system immediately prompted me for a password.  When I try to enter the password I used during the install process, I get the following error:

PS C:\Users\Nick> psql
Password:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Nick"

A few interesting points here.

1. The password obviously doesn't work.
2. postgresql apparently looked at the Windows user that installed it and created an account for it. Cool I suppose.  I'm not sure what this means, though.

So how the heck do I log into this thing?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried with the default `postgres` user? `psql -U postgres`

Comment: If all else fails just edit the `pg_hba.conf` file and set the `local` directive to trust. This should allow you to login with any account. (Don't forget to revert this change once you got in)

Comment: It looks like the postgres user is the one whose password I set during installation!  Thank you.  I'm in

Answer (score 0):

> postgresql apparently looked at the Windows user that installed it and created an account for it. Cool I suppose. I'm not sure what this means, though.

Nope.  In general, PostgreSQL won't give you an indication that the user doesn't exist when password authentication is used.  This is to avoid security information leaking.

For example on my system:

```
$ psql -h localhost -U chris2
Password for user chris2: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "chris2"
$ psql -U chris2
psql: FATAL:  role "chris2" does not exist
```

This is because on my dev system I have trust authentication for UNIX sockets so passwords are not needed.  By default the only account that is created is the 'postgres' account. Also a 'postgres' database is created (for connecting to during db creation).  So that's what you have to log in as.